# Appending along 4th dimension of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4d set of data structured (time,level,lat,lon) that i am trying to interpolate. In order to do so easily i need to add an extra longitude value onto the end of the data with the same values as the first longitude. this will allow the interpolation method i am using to correctly interpolate at higher longitude values(eg 359)

currently data has dimension (64,70,64,128), need to make it have dimension (64,70,64,129) where the values at the last longitude is the same as the ones at the first longitude.

Here is what i have tried so far,

```
data = np.concatenate((data, data[:,:,:,0]), axis = 3)
```

and

```
data = np.append( data, data[:,:,:,0],axis = 3)
```

however i get

```
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
```

for both, i tried adding an extra dimension to the data to append with `data[:,:,:,0][...,np.newaxis]` however that did not help.

At this point I am not sure how to go about doing this, other than looping through each time,level,lat and appending a single value, however i need to perform this operation to hundreds of sets of data so this would get very slow.

Any ideas?

Comment: `np.concatenate((data, data[:,:,:,0][...,None]), axis=3)` should have worked for you.  The `data` indexing could be combined into one [], but doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your arrays need to share the same shape (obviously from the error message), but what that means is that your arrays need to have the same number of dimensions.  The quick answer is use

```
np.append(data, data[:,:,:,0,np.newaxis], axis=3)
# or alternatively in shorthand:
np.append(data, data[...,0,None], axis=-1)
```

Adding either `None` or [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) at the end of your slice adds an extra dimension to the array:

```
>>> data.shape
(64, 70, 64, 128)

>>> data[...,0].shape
(64, 70, 64)

>>> data[...,0,None].shape
(64, 70, 64, 1)
```

This allows the arrays to share the same number of dimensions and the same shape in all dimensions but the one you're appending over.

Comment: Thank you! A tad obvious in retrospect but I didn't understand that grabbing my slice was actually changing the dimensions of the data.